# How can I import KML/KMZ files to Google Maps Engine Lite?

Tags: kml, import, kmz, google-maps-engine

MapsEngine seems to import only CSV, XLS files for creating a map.
How can I import my KML/KMZ files with Maps Engine Lite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is not currently supported to import KML or KMZ to Google Maps Engine Lite or Pro.**

https://support.google.com/mapsenginelite/answer/3024937

The only current way is to use MyMaps (with the Classic Version of Google Maps)

```
Open the classic Google Maps and click My places in the top left corner. (Make sure you’re signed-in).
Click Or create with classic My Maps link under the CREATE MAP button, add a title, then click Import.
Select the KML from from your computer that you’d like to import then click Upload from File. (Note: the maximum file size for import is 3MB).
Click Save then click Done.
```

More info on importing in Google Maps Engines

https://support.google.com/mapsenginelite/answer/3024836

Comment: I've tried and, with this workaround, I manage in import them in maps engine.

Comment: There is a new MyMaps seems to support KML from (Google Drive) https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/maps/NEW$20Mymaps|sort:relevance/maps/uRP5HJMFD5c